# Objectのプロパティにアクセスするメソッド

Tags: javascript

```
let a = {1: "a", 2: "b"};
let accessKey = 1;
```

というようなときに`a`のプロパティ`1`を`accessKey`を使用して参照する方法はあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これでできました

```
console.log(a[accessKey]);
```